# Second Last Login DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

On a Power BI Page where the daily date is selected. The following measure does not work correctly in the scenario where the second last login is yesterday and not today.

```
2ndToLast = CALCULATE(

MINX ( TOPN ( 2, 'AppAccessLog', 'AppAccessLog'[LoginTime] ), 'AppAccessLog'[LoginTime]),

FILTER('Date','Date'[DateId]=SELECTEDVALUE('DateSelector'[DateId],MAX('DateSelector'[DateId]))))+0
```

AppUser X100

Last Login is 2020-02-27 00:02:29.787, Second last is 2020-02-26 17:43:45.900

Returned is for 2nd last login is 2020-02-27 00:02:27.787. This is wrong.

AppUser X100

Last Login is 2020-02-27 00:29:29.153. Second last is 2020-02-27 00:29:07.083

Returned is for 2nd last login is 2020-02-27 00:29:07.083. This is correct.

I have been trying ALL, ALLEXCEPT, ALLSELECTED but nothing working properly thus far. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bad filter on visual and subsequent measure. Case Closed.